# imageview touch event issue in android

Tags: android

I am implementing a drawing canvas and zoom for custom imageview in android. Both are implementing the touch event, if the user touches, I have to draw canvas and if the user flings with two finger I have to zoom imageview. Touch will fire for only one event canvas is working the zoom is not working. Can anybody tell me how to implement these two functionalities?

Thanks

Comment: You can see the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/43627600/7923789

Answer (score 0):

Using a GestureListener you can do it, or you should read all the inputs and make the logic to know what the user is doing.

Comment: Vasconcelos How to implement pinch zoom in gesture listener in android

Comment: You need to read the events and take the difference between the two pointers.